# Glitches while dragging the element fastly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom, dom-events

I want to make a whole div draggable but i want to cahnge its position dynamically while dragging using a specific child of that div (i.e. other area inside that div wont let you move it). I have written a code snippet but it glitches when i move my cursor more rapidly.

Here is the codesandbox link: [codesandbox link](https://codesandbox.io/s/dragging-issue-qzqlyk?file=/src/App.js)

Here is the an example: https://qzqlyk.csb.app/

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, that is happening because your `onMouseMove` event listener is on `box2` div. so event is triggered when you move cursor when it is hovering over `box2`. So when you rapidly move mouse, it goes outside of box for a moment and it does not trigger event.

You can put `onMouseMove={dragMouseMove}` on div with class "App" like this:

```
<div className="App" onMouseMove={dragMouseMove}>
```

and in style you can put this:

```
.App {
      font-family: sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      width: 100vw;
      height: 100vh;
}
```